# Giving course management permission to teacher in Moodle CMS

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I want to give course management(Add new course) permission to teacher in Moodle CMS.
Admin already have this permission under Site Administration. How will I give this permission to Teacher. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Besides admin, there is two system-wide roles: Manager & Course creator.

By the sounds of it, you want the teachers to have the role as Course Creators, so they can create their own courses.

You can apply this role manually at:
Site administration -> Users -> Permissions -> Assign system roles
And then click 'Course creator' to assign this role to users.

Answer (score 0):

Preben is correct, however if you give teachers the 'Course Creators' role they will also get a lot of other permissions you may not want them to have.

Go to:

Site administration -> Users -> Permissions -> Define Roles

Edit the 'teacher' role (by clicking on the cog) then in the permission search bar look for:

moodle/course:create

Change from default 'Not set' to 'Allow'. Teacher will basically be the same role with the added ability to create courses.